# Assigning numerical values to letters in a word

Tags: python, arrays, list, cypher, encoder

I am new to programming. I want to slowly write a program piece by piece that codes and decodes a sentence based on Chapman's code.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah-IzfOzjlZ_ungI4M_yjxY9_kig?e=e6Qzir
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah-IzfOzjlZ_unnDyEXct45dwu60?e=0oK49w

The first piece is to assign the letters of a chosen keyword "CONSTANTINOPLE" their respective numbers.

| C | O | N | S | T | A | N | T | I | N | O | P | L | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 9 | 6 | 12 | 13 | 1 | 7 | 14 | 4 | 8 | 10 | 11 | 5 | 3 |

A is 1.
C is 2 because although it is the 3rd letter of the alphabet, there is no B in the keyword.

So far I have been able to assign the correct numbers to the letters, however, printing them out has them incorrect if there are more than 1 of that letter in the keyword.

```
word = 'constantinople'
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

count = 1
list = [None] * len(word)

for letter in alphabet:
    for char in word:        
        if letter is char:
            list[(word.index(char))] = (count+1)
            count += 1       

print(tuple(word))
print(list)
```

This results in:

```
('c', 'o', 'n', 's', 't', 'a', 'n', 't', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'l', 'e')
[2, 10, 8, 12, 14, 1, None, None, 4, None, None, 11, 5, 3]
```

Which is close to the desired answer of

[2, 9, 6, 12, 13, 1, 7, 14, 4, 8, 10, 11, 5, 3]

The incorrect values are for repeated characters in the keyword (o,n,t). Rather than inserting them into the correct index, the value is incremented it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate for this:

```
m=[i for i in enumerate(sorted(listword), 1)]

for k in m:
    print(k[1], ' equals ', k[0])
```

Output:

```
a  equals  1
c  equals  2
e  equals  3
i  equals  4
l  equals  5
n  equals  6
n  equals  7
n  equals  8
o  equals  9
o  equals  10
p  equals  11
s  equals  12
t  equals  13
t  equals  14
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd like the output ordered so that the letters spell the keyword. I was thinking this could be archieved with a list of  tuples, where each tuple in the list corresponds to the letter in the keyword. If a tuple contains 3 elements, "the letter, the order it occurs in the keyword, the coded number value", it could be sorted by "the order it occurs in the keyword" to have the output in the desired order?